# Sort the list after queuing operation in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, queue

I have to first queue the element in the list and then sort the array based on the first element in the inside the sub list but also maintaining the order in which the elements were inserted if an element was inserted before an element having the same number in the sub list then the element inserted before would appear first.

Ex:

A is our list,inserting first element as [1,2],second element as [2,2],third element as [1,1]

so array would look like the following: 
`A=[[1,2],[1,1],[2,2]]` here [1,1] didnt go to the front because [1,2] was inserted before [1,1] .

By using `A=sorted(A)` after inserting elements results in `A=[[1,1],[1,2],[2,2]]`

code used:( n is the number of elements and b is the sublist to be inserted)

```py
n=int(input())
A=[]
for i in range(n):
    b=list(map(str, input().rstrip().split()))
    A.append(b)
    A=sorted(A)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use  the built-in function `enumerate` to use the insertion order as a second element to order the list:

```
A=[[1,2],[1,1],[2,2]]

A = [e[1] for e in sorted(enumerate(A), key=lambda x: (x[1][0], x[0]))]
# [[1, 2], [1, 1], [2, 2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can sort with the first item of each sub-list as a key instead:

```
A.sort(key=lambda t: t[0])
```

Because the `sort` method maintains the insertion order when two items compare equal.

Excerpt from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort):

> The `sort()` method is guaranteed to be stable. A sort is stable if it
>   guarantees not to change the relative order of elements that compare
>   equal — this is helpful for sorting in multiple passes (for example,
>   sort by department, then by salary grade).